# How to avoid Conditional Expressions from Duplicating Items

Tags: django, django-views

I am trying to annotate a queryset so that a button can appear in the home page (Listview) what there are posts more than one and when there Posts are admin_approved=True

So far the I have reached when there items in the list view with designers related to each item and in the for each post there is a user, in the queryset it checks if there posts related to the designer and these posts should by approvedby_Admin=True so that the button appears.

The issue is that when a user has 2 posts one which is approved and another not approved, 2 items appears and duplication takes place in the homepage List view

I have tried to use .distinct() but it didn't work items are still duplicated

Here is the models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    designer = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    admin_approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

here is the views

```
from .models import Item
from django.db.models import Case, When, BooleanField, Q

class HomeView(ListView):
    model = Item
    paginate_by = 12
    template_name = "home.html"
    ordering = ['-timestamp']

    def get_queryset(self):
        has_post = Case(
            When(Q(designer__post__isnull=False) & Q(designer__post__admin_approved=True), then=True),
            default=False,
            output_field=BooleanField()
        )
        return super().get_queryset().annotate(has_post=has_post).distinct()
```

here is the template

```
{% for item in object_list %}
    {{ item.title }}
    {% if item.has_post %}
        SHOW BUTTON
    {% else %}
        HIDE BUTTON
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

here is the item model

```
class Item(models.Model):
    designer = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Conditional Expressions, you are not passing value when condition evaluates to True,

```
has_post = Case(
            When(designer__post__isnull=False,
            then=True
            default=False,
            output_field=BooleanField()
        )
```

Read more at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/conditional-expressions/